# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost - Connector/J 8.0.32

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

Good day,

What I have in mind:
I have rented a server (Ubuntu 22.04) and installed a mysql server there (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2). I now wanted to run a jar file on the server (Java: OpenJDK Runtime Environment build 18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-222.04) which automatically writes data to my database.

Problem:
When I ran the mysql server on the home computer with the jar program on the PC it worked without any problems.
When I accessed the Mysql server on the server from my home computer, I was also able to write data automatically.
When I now tried to execute the jar file on the server in order to access the Mysql server on the server, I always received the error message:
"No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost".

What I have done so far:
-I enabled port 3306 in the firewall.
-I tried to specify the IP address of my server instead of jdbc:mysql://localhost (jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXX).
-I have inserted the jar file for the Connector/J 8.0.32 (Platform Independent) into my IntelliJ project.
-My user for the mysql server has admin rights and the password is also correct.

Now I don't know what to do. From my PC, I can use the jar file to automatically write data to the mysql server on the server, so the connector/j should work, but it doesn't work with the jar file on the server.

Comment: Hi. Probable the problem is that jar file doesnt have the Connector/J inside. Can you open the jar and check if you have that library?

Answer (score 0):

If you doesnt have the connector/J library into your jar file, just add this dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.28</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I have the mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar in my "External Libraries" in IntelliJ.

Comment: I dont know how it works in IntelliJ, but if is like Spring Tools Suite, it just works in local tests because doesnt package the library into the project